# dlopen stll searching for dependent libary even though the depdenent already got loaded

Tags: linux, dependencies, shared-libraries, dlopen

Say libfoo.so depends on libbar.so (libfoo has DT_NEEDED entry for libar.so, and rpath is set to $ORIGIN). If I use the following:

```
void * handle_bar = dlopen("./dir1/libbar.so", RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NOW);
void * handle_foo = dlopen("./dir2/libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

`handle_foo` will be `NULL` (given that there is no libbar.so in dir2). But if I built libfoo.so without `-lbar`, it works fine. So what's the reason it doesn't detect the library already loaded in case of DT_NEEDED is present? Or is there any other flag I need to use when I load foo?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. What you described _should_ work.